# How to pick a random String from a given list? (Java)

Tags: java, javascript, random

I've made the same in JavaScript, but I'm new to JavaScript and I don't know how to convert it... :/

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
var randomString = new Array ();
randomString[0] = "a random string";
randomString[1] = "another random string";
randomString[2] = "another random string";
randomString[3] = "another random string";
randomString[4] = "another random string";
randomString[5] = "another random string";
randomString[6] = "another random string";
randomString[7] = "another random string";
var i = Math.floor(7*Math.random())

document.write(randomString[i]);
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe show us your first try.

Comment: Java and JavaScript are not at all the same thing.

Comment: If you are asking for Java code, please tag your question so. It is not sure what you are asking for

Comment: [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

Comment: You've got 8 elements, not just 7. Better use `Math.floor(randomStrings.length*Math.random())`

Comment: @Bergi that's precisely why I added it into my (rather rusty Java) answer below.

Answer (score 4):

You have several options in Java. You can accomplish the same strategy you used here by using a String array:

```
String[] randomString = new String[8];
randomString[0] = "a random string";
randomString[1] = "another random string";
randomString[2] = "another random string";
randomString[3] = "another random string";
randomString[4] = "another random string";
randomString[5] = "another random string";
randomString[6] = "another random string";
randomString[7] = "another random string";
int i = Math.floor(randomString.length * Math.random());

System.out.println(randomString[i]);
```

Another option is to use the [Java Collections Framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/collections/index.html) and use something like a List:

```
List<String> randomStrings = new LinkedList<String>();
randomStrings.add("a random string");
randomStrings.add("another random string");
randomStrings.add("another random string");
```

Once you have a List, you can do several things:

```
Collections.shuffle(randomStrings);
System.out.println(randomStrings.get(0));
```

or:

```
int i = Math.floor(randomStrings.size() * Math.random());
System.out.println(randomStrings.get(i));
```

The Collections.shuffle is going to actually modify the list and shuffle the elements around, so be aware of that.

Comment: The shuffle approach is particularly handy if you plan to pick out several random strings or you want a list of strings in random order. Again, keep in mind it's modifying the List, so the larger the list, the more expensive that call is.

Answer (score 0):

My Java is a bit rusty, but how's this?

```
List<String> s = new List<String>(); //better than an array, because those are bounded
s.add("this is a string"); // first string
//repeat

int i = new Random().nextInt(s.size()); 
//from 0 - size exclusive, and the array starts at 0, so this is good

String result = s.get(i);
```

Comment: Are list indexes (in `get`) really one-based? That's interesting.

Comment: @Bergi there was that little bit about "rusty" ;-)